# Form is not working for school project. I must also get the answers into an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, forms

The html seems to be fine from what I can see it's the javascript that is not working. I also need to get the answers into an array but that is a later problem that I can deal with.

```
     <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Content:</legend>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="content" value="bad"/>bad</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="content" value="average"/> average</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="content" value="good"/> good</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="content" value="excellent"/> excellent</label>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
                <legend>Style:</legend><h5>the site needs more:</h5>
                <label2><input type ="checkbox" name="style"value="color"/>color</label2>
                <label2><input type ="checkbox" name="style" value="whitespace"/> 
       whitespace</label2>
                <label2><input type ="checkbox" name="style"value="Texture"/> Texture</label2>
                <label2><input type ="checkbox" name="style" value="Icons"/> Icons</label2>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
                <legend>Usability:</legend>  
                <label><input type ="radio" name="usability" value="bad"/>bad</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name="usability" value="average"/> average</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name="usability" value="good"/> good</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name="usability" value="excellent"/> excellent</label>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
                <legend>Theme:</legend>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="Theme" value="bad"/>bad</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="Theme" value="average"/> average</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="Theme" value="good"/> good</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="Theme" value="excellent"/> excellent</label>
        </fieldset>
        <br>   
        <fieldset>
                <legend>Optimization</legend>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="Optimization" value="bad"/>bad</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="Optimization" value="average"/> average</label>
                <label><input type ="radio" name ="Optimization" value="good"/> good</label>
          <label><input type ="radio" name ="Optimization" value="excellent"/> excellent</label>
        </fieldset>        
        <input type="button" value ="Submit">
    </form>
```

The event listener is not working i assume its because of the check function has to have something wrong.I am still learning the basics.

```js
    var contentflag = false, styleflag = false, usabilityflag = false, themeflag = optimizationflag 
 = false;
          
          var btnSubmit = document.querySelector("input[type='button']");
          
           
          btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", check);
          
          function check(){
            
            var messages = [];
            messages.push(checkcontent());  
            messages.push(checkstyle());
            messages.push(checkusability());
   messages.push(checktheme());
   messages.push(checkoptimization());
      
            if (contentflag && styleflag && usabilityflag && themeflag && optimizationflag){
             
              var content = document.querySelector("input[name='content']:checked").value;
              
              var styleFields = 
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[name='style']:checked"));
              
             
              var style = styleFields.map(function(item){
                return item.value;
              });
              
              
              style = style.join(", ");
              
              var usability = document.querySelector("input[name='usability']:checked").value;
              var theme = document.querySelector("input[name='theme']:checked").value;
     var optimization = document.querySelector("input[name='optimization']:checked").value;
             
              alert("thank you for your input");
            } else {
             var message = messages.join(", ");
              alert("You haven't selected: " + message);
            }
          } 
      
          function checkcontent(){ 
           if(document.querySelector("input[name='content']:checked")){
              contentflag = true;
            } else { 
              contentflag = false; 
              return "content";
            }
          }
      
          function checkstyle(){ 
            if(document.querySelector("input[name='style']:checked")){
             styleflag = true;
            } else { 
              styleflag = false;
              return "style"; 
            }   
          }
      
          function checkusability(){ 
            if (document.querySelector("input[name='usability']:checked")){
    usabilityflag = true;
            } else {
    usabilityflag = false;
              return "usability"; 
            }
          }
      
          function checktheme(){ 
            if (document.querySelector("input[name='theme']:checked")){
    themeflag = true;
            } else { 
    themeflag = false;
              return "theme";
            }
   
   function checkoptimization(){ 
    if (document.querySelector("input[name='optimizationt']:checked")){
     optimizationflag = true;
    } else { 
     optimizationflag = false;
      return "optimization";
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your javascript code snippet it gives the error message:

```
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null",
```

That means that your variable btnSubmit isn't the submit button.

```js
document.querySelector("input[type='button']");
```

This gives a valid element if you have only one input with type button in your document. Do you have more outside the HTML that you posted here? You could solve it by giving it an id, e.g. id="btn-submit" and than do

```js
var btnSubmit = document.querySelector("#btn-submit")
```

or

```js
var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("btn-submit")
```

Comment: you are correct i did have buttons on the html somewhere else

Comment: i really appreciate the help.

Comment: you were right there was multiple buttons and i tried what you said but it didn't quite work. So I gave the button an onclick to start the function check. Now i have more problems but thank you for getting me on the right track.